# unable to install nodejs modules

Tags: node.js, websocket, npm-install

Probably someone asked before but unable to find any solution after extensive search on here or on the web.

Successfully installed nodeja V8.x on my Centos 7, and tried to use WebSocket library.  Search on the web and all instructions are simply telling me to run `npm -install ws`.

Got error:

```
saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
```

Looks like it is looking for some local package file.

Any help is appropriated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh, finally got it. Need to run `npm init` first to create the JSON file.